# Set fixed reference scale for QGIS layer with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, rendering

Is it possible to set a fixed reference scale for a QGIS layer using PyQGIS?

[image]

I try this script but it doesn't work:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

r = QgsFeatureRenderer()
r.setReferenceScale(400_000)
lyr.setRenderer(r)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a reference scale by getting the renderer of the active layer. You don't need to make a new `QgsFeatureRenderer`.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
r = lyr.renderer()
r.setReferenceScale(400_000)
```